# Taking value of a range of merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of merged cells with values in them. I would simply like to read the value contained in each merged cell. The amount of cells in the merge area varies. Right now I have this:

```
Sub testnoms()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B20:K23") 'this would be the range to look at
        Debug.Print cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Right now it goes to every cell in the range and returns the value in its merged area. So I get the right values, but I have a duplicate for every cell in the merged area. For example, if 5 cells are merged together, it prints 5 times the value of the merged cell. Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub testnoms()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B20:K23") 
        If cell.Address() = cell.MergeArea.Cells(1).Address() Then
            Debug.Print cell.Address(), cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you need to capture merged area values which may not be full-contained in your defined range:

```
Sub testnoms()
    Dim c As Range, d, addr
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("B20:K23")
        addr = c.MergeArea.Address()
        If Not d.exists(addr) Then
            d.Add addr, True
            Debug.Print c.Address(), c.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I made the assumption that each merged area is fully-contained in the range you're looping over: if that's not the case then a different approach might be needed.

Comment: It is the case. Although from what I understand of merged cells, it is true your method would not work if the merged area protruded from the top or the left of the cell, otherwise it would still work it if protruded from the bottom or right by taking the first cell (which would still be in the indicated range).

Comment: If you wanted to handle merged area which are partly outside of your area then the most robust approach would be to keep track of the mergearea addresses and only report the cell value if you haven't already seen that address.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the range B20:K23, use B20:B23.  Using the B:K Range, it will (as you noticed) go through each 'underlying' cell in that merged cell and return the same value over and over.  If you use B:B instead, it'll act as you wanted it to - go through each merged cell ONCE and return that value.

Does that make sense?

edit: Please let me know why downvotes, I am also trying to learn, so if this method is not a good one, kindly let me know why so I can learn too.

Comment: The merged cells are not one on top of the other. Sometimes they are next to each other. Your method would ignore that.

Comment: You get downvotes because you assume each merged cell range is a full area from column B to K, which is most probably wrong, since nothing the OPs question indicates that.